# Suitable test functions for finite element solution as a subset of $S_0^h(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, elementary-set-theory, partial-differential-equations

Given a test function $\phi$ definition

$$
\phi_j(x_i, y_i) = \begin{cases}
1, & i = j, \\
0, & i \neq j,
\end{cases}
$$

for the finite element solution to a PDE with exact solution $u$

$$
U(x_i, y_i) = U_i = \sum_{j=1}^{N_{nodes}}U_j \phi_j(x_i, y_i),
$$

on a domain $\Omega$ with Dirichlet boundary conditions $u = 0$ on $\partial \Omega$ and mesh nodes $i \in [1...N_{nodes}]$, then $\phi_i(x_i, y_i) = 1$ even if the nodal coordinates $(x_i, y_i) \in \partial \Omega$. This implies that $\phi_i \notin S_0^h$ for

$$
\begin{aligned}
S^h &= \{ \text{functions V given by} \ V(x, y) = \sum_{j=1}^{N_{nodes}} V_j \phi_j(x, y)\ \\ &\text{where}\ \phi_j\ \text{are suitably defined basis functions}  \} \\
S_E^h &= \{ V \in S^h\ |\ V \text{ satisfies all Dirichlet boundary conditions} \} \\
S_0^h &= \{ V \in S^h\ |\ V(x,y) = 0 \textbf{ at all points where Dirichlet boundary conditions apply.} \}
\end{aligned}
$$

but section 7.6.2 of the book "Finite Element Methods: A Practical Guide" (Whiteley 2017) claims **"suppose that a node $i$ does not lie on the boundary, $\partial \Omega$. Then it follows that $\phi_i \in S_0^h(\Omega)$". How is this claim true?** I would think that because $S_0^h \subset S^h$, one could not make the above claim since $\phi_i$ could be in $S^h$ and there is no guarantee that it is also in $S_0^h$. In other words, just because the node $i$ is not on the boundary, it does not guarantee that $\phi_i \in S_0^h$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is actually given by the definition of the test function

$$
\phi_j(x_i, y_i) = \begin{cases}
1, & i = j, \\
0, & i \neq j.
\end{cases}
$$

If the node $i$ is on the domain $\Omega$ where $\Omega\ \cap\ \partial \Omega = \emptyset$, then this means that if you evaluate $\phi$ at any other node $j$ where $j \neq i$ and could lie on the boundary $\partial \Omega$, $\phi_j(x_i, y_i) = 0$. Because $V(x, y) = \sum_{j=1}^{N_{nodes}} V_j \phi_j(x, y)$, then $V(x, y) = V_j$ iff $j = i$, otherwise V(x, y) = 0, which implies that $\phi_i \in S_0^h$.

[image]